# Aligning Three Images Horizontally (Can only get them vertical)

Tags: html, css, alignment

I seem to be really missing something about how to line three images horizontally in one block across the screen with CSS. I seem to only be able to line them up in one long line down the page (when I really want them to go across the screen in a horizontal line). Where am I doing wrong with my div? Or maybe I am being led astray in CSS? Any ideas? Thank you so much.

```css
.taco_container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="taco_container">
    <div class="taco">
       <a href="tacogame_choose_1.html">
          <img src="images/tacoone.png" style="width:304px;height:228px">
       </a>
    </div>
    <div class="taco">
       <a href="tacogame_choose_2.html">
          <img src="images/tacotwo.png" style="width:304px;height:228px">
       </a>
    </div>
    <div class="taco">
       <a href="tacogame_choose_3.html">
          <img src="images/tacothree.png">
       </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, for starters, your container is 300px wide and your first two images are 304px wide each.

Comment: `div`s are `block` elements and will begin on new lines. `a` are `inline` elements and will stay on the same line. In your example it appears that the `.taco` `div`s are superfluous, removing them will enable the links to display in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `display` items as `inline-block` and set `text-align: center`.

```
.taco_container {
    width: 100%;
}
.taco {
    width: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2xo1gr6w/

Answer (score 2):

your solution may be: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3z1opsgf/1/)
i added only class :"img_class" and remove inline style sheet

```css
.taco_container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.img_class{width:33%;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="taco_container">
    <div class="taco">
       <a href="tacogame_choose_1.html">
          <img  class="img_class" src="images/tacoone.png">
       </a>
    </div>
    <div class="taco">
       <a href ="tacogame_choose_2.html">
          <img class="img_class" src="images/tacotwo.png" >
       </a>
    </div>
    <div class="taco">
       <a href="tacogame_choose_3.html">
          <img  class="img_class" src="images/tacothree.png">
       </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check here an example also with display:inline : http://jsfiddle.net/y1tuLyzg/

```
#taco_container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
    padding:0;
}
#taco_container .taco {
    display:inline-block;
    width:33%;
    height:100px;
}
#taco_container .taco img {
    max-width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost! You just needed to add `display:inline-block;` to `.taco`:

```
.taco {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/chriz123/42e3mfke/1/) (excuse the kittens they are an example)

Also `taco_container` has a width of `300px` and each image has a width of `304px`, so you would need to increase the width of `taco_container` accordingly to fit with the images.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.taco_container {
  width: 300px;  <!-- wrapping div is smaller than the divs you trying to put in it-->
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="taco_container">
    <div class="taco">
       <a href="tacogame_choose_1.html">
          <img src="images/tacoone.png" style="width:304px;height:228px">
       </a>
    </div>
    <div class="taco">
       <a href="tacogame_choose_2.html">
          <img src="images/tacotwo.png" style="width:304px;height:228px">
       </a>
    </div>
    <div class="taco">
       <a href="tacogame_choose_3.html">
          <img src="images/tacothree.png">
       </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your wrapping div or container is 300px yet you are trying to put 3 divs that are 304px wide into it.

Answer (score 0):

```
.taco_container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.taco { display: inline-block;
width:30%;}
```

```
<div id="taco_container">
    <div class="taco">
       <a href="tacogame_choose_1.html">
          <img src="images/tacoone.png" style="height:228px">
       </a>
    </div>
    <div class="taco">
       <a href="tacogame_choose_2.html">
          <img src="images/tacotwo.png" style="height:228px">
       </a>
    </div>
    <div class="taco">
       <a href="tacogame_choose_3.html">
          <img src="images/tacothree.png">
       </a>
    </div>
</div>
```